Use event handler to update map view in ipyleaflet
Previous project people developed the app on Python shiny. Project partners requested the map does not revert back to its original center and zoom when adding visualization layers, so I was hoping to see if there's a way in ipyleaflet to use event handlers to track the UI activity and then reflect that information in the map. Any ideas?
`   last_center = [44.44343571548758,-84.36155640717737]
last_zoom = 6
@output
@render_widget
def map():
    basemap = basemaps[input.basemap()]
    layerlist = input.layers()

    the_map = L.Map(basemap=basemap,
                 center= last_center, 
                 zoom= last_zoom,  layout=Layout(width="100%", height="100%"))
    markerorcircle = False


    if "Marker (name, address, # sites, source)" in layerlist:
        build_marker_layer(LARA_C = 0)
        marker_cluster = L.MarkerCluster(
            name='location markers',
            markers=tuple(mklist_mh)
            )
        the_map.add_layer(marker_cluster)
        markerorcircle = True
    if "Marker LARA (name, address, # sites, source)" in layerlist:
        build_marker_layer(LARA_C = 1)
        marker_cluster = L.MarkerCluster(
            name='location markers',
            markers=tuple(mklist_lara)
            )
        the_map.add_layer(marker_cluster)
        markerorcircle = True
    if "Legislative districts (Michigan State Senate)" in layerlist:
        build_district_layers(upper = 1)
        the_map.add_layer(upper_layers[0])
    if "Legislative districts (Michigan State House of Representatives)" in layerlist:
        build_district_layers(upper = 0)
        the_map.add_layer(lower_layers[0])

    return the_map`

I have no idea at all how to do this. And have no clue where to find more since the documentation seems to suggest you CAN'T do this.
